# How to float two elements in li element without clearing each time

Tags: html, css, css-float, html-lists

I am having a stacked list where I want to float an img (icon) and the text. However, I feel its a pain to clear after each list item. What's the solution here? Any tips how to make it more clean?

```
<ul>
  <li><img src="#" /> <a href="#">Home</a></li>
  <div class="clear"></div>
  <li><img src="#" /> <a href="#">About</a></li>
  <div class="clear"></div>
</ul>
```

Comment: `div` as a direct child of `ul` isn't a valid html

Comment: is this whatyou mean? http://jsfiddle.net/S3kej/

Comment: or this? http://jsfiddle.net/S3kej/1

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/rHxCb/ using `css padding`

Comment: I'd use the image as background and remove it from the markup altogether

Comment: Thanks @MichaelUnterthurner Clearing once after ul works now!

Comment: @domdev pls vote for the right answer

Comment: @MichaelUnterthurner The solution I used was the comment from 3rror404, using the image as background. That's why I marked his comment as useful.

Answer (score 1):

You could make the `li` elements to `clear`..

```
<ul>
  <li class="clear"><img src="#" /> <a href="#">Home</a></li>
  <li class="clear"><img src="#" /> <a href="#">About</a></li>
</ul>
```

---

If you only float the contents of the `li` (*the `img` and the `a`*) then you can just set the `overflow` of the `li` to `auto` or `hidden` and it will work as expected.

```
li{overflow:auto;}
```

**Demo at** http://jsfiddle.net/SqWHB/

Comment: @MohammadAreebSiddiqui, nope. the default is `overflow:visible` (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/overflow)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, use a class for the clearfix:

and add this css:

```
.clearfix:before, .clearfix:after {
    display: table;
    line-height: 0;
    content: "";
}

.clearfix:after {
      clear: both;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need the clear only one time and that is after the ul.

```
<ul>
   <li><img src="#" /> <a href="#">Home</a></li>
   <li><img src="#" /> <a href="#">About</a></li>
</ul>
<div class="clear"></div>
```